# How to get button to display on click

Tags: javascript, button

Using JavaScript (or jQuery), create a variable called “myName” and set the value to your “myName” 
Create a , that when you click it, it displays an alert with your “myName” variable. 
Here is the problem I am currently working. I am super new to this and just trying to figure this out. Here is the code I currently have, when I click the button it displays nothing.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <style type=text/css>
    div1 {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    div2 {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: red;
    }

  </style>

  <body>

    <div1 id="myName"><b>Woolley</b></div1>

    <div2 class="Hobbies">Hockey</div2>

    <div2 class="Hobbies">Hiking</div2>

    <button type="button" onclick=var "myName"Woolley>Button</button>

  </body>

</html>


java script 

var "myName"
 "Woolley"
```

Comment: [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) is different from [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)

Answer (score 2):

you can check below code to change the value

```
<p id="changeName">Mark</p>
<button type="button" class="myevent">Button</button>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
    $('.myevent').on('click', function(){
       var name = "John Doe";
       $('#changeName').val(name);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is Jquery function please inlcude jquery library before use this.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Javascript:

```
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
      <style type=text/css>
        div1 {
          background-color: yellow;
        }

        div2 {
          background-color: #000000;
          color: red;
        }

      </style>
      <script>
        function displayName(){
          var myName = "Woolley";
          alert(myName);
        }
      </script>

      <body>

        <div1 id="myName"><b>Woolley</b></div1>

        <div2 class="Hobbies">Hockey</div2>

        <div2 class="Hobbies">Hiking</div2>

        <button type="button" onclick="displayName()">Button</button>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- To make the  `onclick` on your button do something, tell the `onclick` what to do when triggered; In this case, I told it do execute the function `myFunction`.
- In this function, create your variable and alert it using `alert()`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myName = "Woolley";
  alert(myName);
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<style type=text/css>
  div1 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  
  div2 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div1 id="myName"><b>Woolley</b></div1>

  <div2 class="Hobbies">Hockey</div2>

  <div2 class="Hobbies">Hiking</div2>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>

</body>

</html>
```

---

If you don't want to use a function, you can also tell `onclick` to execute `alert()` without a function:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="var myName = 'Woolley'; alert(myName);">Button</button>
```

Please note that you need to use `"` and `'` properly, otherwise your HTML is invalid and can't execute your JavaScript.